# anonymous function syntax difference

Tags: javascript, function

I am a little confused about anonymous function syntax. I tried to search the similar discussion but I dont know which keyword should I type.

case 1: missing () before function

```
example1: function() {
  var a = 1, b = 2;
  return a + b;
}();
```

case 2: standard anonymous function

```
example2: (function() {
  var a = 2, b = 3;
  return a + b;
})();
```

when I execute two functions like this:

```
xxx.example1  // show 3
```

and

```
xxx.example2  // show 5
```

Both of them will show correct values. What are they different?

Comment: There are no different keywords. The second function expression is wrapped in grouping parenthesis to indicate that it's executed right away instead of being assigned